# WordPress - Adding .active class to active menu item's sub pages?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

There is a problem in `wp_nav_menu` below:

Nav.php:

```
    $arg = array(
        'container' => false,
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
    );
    wp_nav_menu($arg);
```

functions.php:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Output:

```
<ul id="menu-quinn-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="http://xxx/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item current_page_parent menu-item-14 active "><a href="http://xxx/work/">Work</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="http://xxx/shop/">Shop</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-12"><a href="http://xxx/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can see the class `active` in the Work's `li`, but when I go to the sub pages of Work (parent), the output:

```
<ul id="menu-quinn-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-15"><a href="http://xxx/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-14"><a href="http://xxx/work/">Work</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="http://xxx/shop/">Shop</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-12"><a href="http://xxx/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

You **don't** see the class `active` in the Work's `li` anymore.

Any ideas how I can have `active` in the Work's `li`'s sub pages?

Comment: Why not just reference the class `current_page_parent` ?

Comment: Did you try changing `current-menu-item` to `current_page_parent` in your function?

Comment: @Carlton `Why not just reference the class current_page_parent?` how do I change that?

Comment: @JaredThomas How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the block you pasted from your `functions.php` file from:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

to:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if( in_array('current_page_parent', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
return $classes;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use CSS and select `current_page_parent` since Wordpress automatically adds that class to the page's parent as well.